# Symfony (Doctrine) 2: Entity ManyToMany Relationship with itself

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity "Product". A Product can be a "package" (boolean) which then consists of Products. A Product can be a part of many packages. As such, I need to map a ManyToMany relationship in Product with itself, so that I have $packageProducts in a mapping table with "package_id" and "product_id".

How do I define the ManyToMany relationship inside the "Product" entity to map to itself? I know you need to define your join table and you mappedColumn and inverseColumn, but I do not know exactly how to do this.

Current Product Entity (ManyToMany mapping not yet included):

```
<?php

namespace LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Ser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @Ser\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="package", type="boolean")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    protected $package;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    protected $active;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_range", type="string", length=32)
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    protected $range;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=128)
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var text
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var File
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\File", cascade={"remove","persist"})
     * @Ser\Expose
     **/
    protected $displayImage;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @var Deliverable[]
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Deliverable", mappedBy="product", cascade={"remove"})
     **/
    protected $deliverables;
}
```

**EDIT:** When I add the following to my Product Entity

```
/**
 * @var Product[]
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="packageProducts")
 **/
protected $packages;

/**
 * @var Product[]
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="packages")
 **/
protected $packageProducts;
```

I get a mapping table "product_product" with a single field "product_id". I need this to be "package_products" with fields "product_id", "package_id". How do I define this in the ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
/**
 * @var Product[]
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="packageProducts")
 **/
protected $packages;

/**
 * @var Product[]
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="packages")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="package_products",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="package_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 * @Ser\Expose()
 **/
protected $packageProducts;
```

You add the JoinTable information on the property that will do the mapping (ie: The one that has the inversedBy="" on it).

Comment: For more information: [http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing)

Answer (score 0):

In the same class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="packages")
 */
private $package;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="package")
 */
private $packages;
```

Comment: Hi Roberto, it needs to be a MANY TO MANY relationship, as the same product can be in many packages. If it was many to one (One package can have many products but the product can only have one package) then it would not have been a problem. My problem comes in with the MANY TO MANY part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating one relation ManyToMany, you can create two realtion OneTOMany with another entity.

```
<?php 
 namespace LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Ser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

use LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Product;

class ProductPackage{
   /**
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="packages")
 */
private $package;

  /**
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="products")
 */
private $product;


public function setProduct(Product $product){
    $this->product = $product;
    $product->setProduct($this);
}

public function getProduct(){
    return $this->product;
}

public function setPackage(Product $package){
    $this->package = $package;
    $package->setPackage($this);
}

public function getPackage(){
    return $this->Package;
}

 }
?>
```

-Then you add to the product entity this:

```
    use LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\ProductPackage;// in the use declaration section      
    /**
     *
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\ProductPackage", mappedBy="product", cascade={"remove"})
     */

     private $products;
   /**
     *
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LittleGiant\PortalBundle\Entity\ProductPackage", mappedBy="package", cascade={"remove"})
     */

     private $packages;
    public function getProducts(){
        return $this->products;
    }
    public function setProducs(ProductPackage $pp){
        $this->products[] = $pp;
    }
 public function getPackages(){
        return $this->package;
    }
    public function setPackage(ProductPackage $pp){
        $this->packages[] = $pp;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I specifically did not want to use a bridging entity and wanted Symfony to handle the mapping table automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the docs (see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing):
I had to edit the "getFriendsWithMe" method to get friends for ALL users (the original user where the friends are added and vice versa: The "new" friends of the user should also display the original user as their friend):

```
public function getFriendsWithMe()
{
    return new ArrayCollection(
        array_merge(array_merge($this->friendsWithMe->toArray(), $this->myFriends->toArray()))
    );
}
```